# Flag post to another website of the stackexchange network - why so few choices?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

I followed the following steps to flag a post as "to move to another stackexchange website":

1) flag

2) it should be closed for another reason

3) off-topic because

4) This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

And here I was prompted just 5 websites.. the question I'm referring was this: [Disable or hide fields that are not applicable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388591/disable-or-hide-fields-that-are-not-applicable) and it belonged to the https://ux.stackexchange.com/ website (at least in my opinion).

Why so few options?

Comment: I would argue that, at the very least, the "this question belongs on another site" should have a radio button option with an attached textbox that you could type in. This would then convert on the backend to just being a generic mod flag with text like "off-topic: belongs in [whatever]", just so people don't have to *know* that that is what you're supposed to do with such things. I've flagged a good number to "belongs on Android.SE", "belongs on Programmers", or career, or electronics... never flagged one to tex or sharepoint.

Comment: The linked duplicate contains the correct answer for **how** to migrate to any site. The specific reason of **why** there are so few choices is to prevent crap being migrated.